# Java not detecting a class file in the same directory

Tags: java

While working on a project in my spare time, I came across 2 errors

```
Error:(3, 9) cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Human
  location: class tester

Error:(3, 25) cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Human
  location: class tester
```

However, the Human class is created in another file in the same directory as my tester class.

Human class:

```
public class Human extends Character{

  private boolean excercising;
  private boolean studying;

  public Human(){this(0,0.0,0,0,"<NoName>");} //default Constructor 
                                             //calls non-default 
                                             //constructor <below>

  public Human(int i, double j, int k, int l, String m ){ //non- 
                                   //default constructor, didn't 
                                   //feel like making over 2
    intellect = i;                 //constructors                       
    height = j;
    age = k;
    strength = l;
    name = m;
  }

  public void Exercising(int time){ //In retrospect, this and 
                                    //Studying could have been 
                                    //done in the set methods but
    excercising = true;             // whatever, it's a good way 
to demonstrate class calls.
    for(int t = 0; t < time; t++){
      setStrength();                // Class call with no 
                                    //parameters
    }
    excercising = false;
  }

  public void setStrength(){
    if(excercising){
      strength = strength + 1;     //long increment (can change 
                                  //increment factor to 2, 3, etc.)
    }
  }

  public void Studying(int time){
    studying = true;
    for(int t = 0; t < time; t++){  //standard for-loop
      setIntellect();
    }
    studying = false;
  }

  public void setIntellect(){
    if(studying){
      intellect++;            //super-simple increment only by 1
    }
  }

  public void birthday(){
    age+=1;               //simple increment (can change increment factor to 2, 3, etc.)
    System.out.println("Happy Birthday to " + name + " who is now 
                       "+ age +" years old.");
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Human " + super.toString();
  }
}
```

tester class:

```
public class tester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Human bob = new Human();
        System.out.println(bob.toString());
    }
}
```

I expected it to return a string, instead I got the class not found error.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1 in case that is important.

Comment: Would you please provide a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: also would be nice to see the whole code, better a [mcve] - are you using the `package` statement? any `import`?

Comment: Basic Question just to be sure: Did you define a Package for Human and tester? If so, did you import the Human class in your tester? In your provided Code they are both in the default Package.

Comment: First of all, `Character` is a final class, so you cannot extend it. In addition to that, if you comment out stuff related to that parent class, every thing works fine.

Comment: David, i'm new to using Intellij so, how do I define a package.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can't do ".toString()" on an object, you should do and use bob.getName() instead of bob.toString():

public class Human extends Character{

```
 String name;

 public void setName(String name){
     this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName(){
        return name;
 }

 public Human(String name){
        this.setName(name)
 }
```

}

Comment: Of course you can do toString on an object. It is implemented in the Object class so it can be called on objects of any class

Comment: and how is that supposed to answer the question (cannot find symbol)???

Comment: I didn't know that we can do that, sorry.

Comment: Then please delete this answer